# xcodebuild DVT Assertion Fails with "Unexpectedly found two active proxied devices"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, ios-simulator

This just started happening. There is nothing I've done in between it working normally and it causing this error other than running `ionic run ios`.

This is the configuration and full error output:

```
Build settings from command line:
    ARCHS = i386
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/caffeinewriter/Code/Ionic/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator10.1
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/caffeinewriter/Code/Ionic/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
    VALID_ARCHS = i386

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/caffeinewriter/Code/Ionic/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = DEBUG=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include" "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
    IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 8.0
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
    TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY = 1,2

2016-12-01 17:40:06.519 xcodebuild[3200:26075]  DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-11515/IDEiOSSupportCore/DVTiPhoneSimulator.m:615
Details:  Unexpectedly found two active proxied devices for companion dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:0AFB07EE-AC31-49BE-BAE6-EADE7895ED81: dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:7A73CA0B-A1C0-4280-AF61-CDF55905A3D0 and dvtdevice-iphonesimulator:7A73CA0B-A1C0-4280-AF61-CDF55905A3D0
Object:   <DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7fe7d853cc00>
Method:   -_updateProxiedDeviceSet
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fe7d8344390>{number = 7, name = (null)}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0   -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   __45-[DVTiPhoneSimulator _updateProxiedDeviceSet]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEiOSSupportCore)
  4   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
  5   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
  6   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
  7   _dispatch_queue_serial_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
  8   _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
  9   _dispatch_queue_override_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
 10   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
 11   _dispatch_worker_thread3 (in libdispatch.dylib)
 12   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
 13   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
/Users/caffeinewriter/Code/Ionic/platforms/ios/build/emulator/FAPL.app/Info.plist file not found.
```

So far I've tried the following things:

- Restarting my computer.
- Removing and re-adding the ionic platforms.
- Searching for references to those device IDs in the ionic project folder. (`grep -Rl 0AFB07EE .` and `grep -Rl 7A73CA0B .`)
- Resetting Simulator content and settings.
- Removing Xcode and `~/Library/Developer`

I'm really lost on what to try next, and the only references I could find to this specific error were on some Chinese Cocoa boards, and I'm really lost.

It also results in Xcode crashing as soon as I attempt to open it. <strike>Is there any solution other than completely reinstalling Xcode and hoping for the best?</strike>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset simulators to fix this bug

`sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin snapshot`

`snapshot reset_simulators`

Comment: This appears to do the trick! The exact actions that it takes are located in [this file](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/bff799b14e62d92070c1e040b74d9e5eadda762d/snapshot/lib/snapshot/reset_simulators.rb), though snapshot does automate the process.